# Scala macros: How can I get a list of the objects within a given package that inherit some trait?

Tags: scala, scala-macros

I have a package `foo.bar` in which a trait `Parent` is defined, and a series of objects `Child1`, `Child2`, `Child3` are defined. I would like to get a `List[Parent]` containing all child objects defined in `foo.bar`. How can I write such a macro?

Right now I have the following:

```
  def myMacro(c: blackbox.Context): c.Expr[Set[RuleGroup]] = {
    val parentSymbol = c.mirror.staticClass("foo.bar.Parent")
    c.mirror.staticPackage("foo.bar").info.members
      // get all objects
      .filter { sym =>
      // remove $ objects
      sym.isModule && sym.asModule.moduleClass.asClass.baseClasses.contains(parentSymbol)
    }.map { ??? /* retrieve? */ }
    ???
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you'd be looking for:

`.map(sym => c.mirror.reflectModule(sym.asModule).instance.asInstanceOf[Parent])`

Later edit:

I have tried doing this in a trait, so not a macro like above, and when calling it with a different package than the one calling it from, it returned an empty collection of objects. Reading through it might have to do with how classloaders work in Scala as they don't have the knowledge of all the classes being loaded, but i see your macro doesn't use a classloader so maybe it still works in your case.

For me it worked using the [Reflections](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections) library like this in a trait:

```
import org.reflections.Reflections

import scala.reflect.runtime.universe
import scala.reflect.{ClassTag, classTag}
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

trait ChildObjects {
  def childObjectsOf[Parent: ClassTag](containingPackageFullName: String): Set[Parent] = {
    new Reflections(containingPackageFullName)
      .getSubTypesOf(classTag[Parent].runtimeClass)
      .asScala
      .map(cls => {
        val mirror = universe.runtimeMirror(cls.getClassLoader)
        val moduleSymbol = mirror.moduleSymbol(cls)
        mirror.reflectModule(moduleSymbol).instance.asInstanceOf[Parent]
      })
      .toSet
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the `trait` is not `sealed` you can't do that. Fundamentally if a `trait` is not `sealed`, it means new subclasses can be added later under different compilation unit.

If the `trait` is `sealed`, than you can use `knownDirectSubclasses` of [ClassSymbolApi](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.4/scala-reflect/scala/reflect/api/Symbols$ClassSymbolApi.html) but beware of the possible issues the depend on order such as [this](https://github.com/circe/circe/issues/434) and [this in circe](https://github.com/circe/circe/issues/639)

Comment: I just want the child objects defined from within the same package. I already have a list of symbols, I just don't know how to resolve/instantiate/retrieve the actual objects.

Comment: @CarlPatenaudePoulin, you don't show your real high-level problem but what you are trying to do is fundamentally unsafe and thus the compiler is not going to help you doing that. If you really have a small list of those subtypes, make the trait `sealed` and move them all into a single file (which is required for the compiler to ensure that the trait is really `sealed`) and then use the API I linked. Otherwise I'd say you are doing something wrong.

Comment: "I just want the child objects defined from within the same package." – You can't because anybody anywhere anytime can define new child objects within the same package. How is your macro supposed to return you an object that I will only create next year?